# vSphere Client not allowing export of OVF template

Tags: vmware-vsphere, export, ovf

I have a vm that I can access via vSphere Client and Remote Desktop (RDC). It is a Windows Server 2003 image. I am trying to export it locally via menu option OVF Template option. **The option is unfortunately grayed out**.

[image]

In what circumstances would this occur?

The server is powered down.

Can snapshots exist?

Comment: What version of VMware are you using?

Comment: vSphere Client 5, vCenter Server 5

Comment: vSphere Client is a client component, vCenter Server is a management component. What hypervisor? Presumably vSphere, but what version?

Comment: My host won't grant the permissions necessary to Export OVF Template, is there another way besides obtaining permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I could not export is due to not having permissions (Power User not Administrator).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ovftool? It comes off as very handy to export ovf/ova

Answer (score 1):

## Enable in custom Role

If you're using a custom Role and wish to grand the ability to do "OVF Export",
You need to ensure  **`vApp -> Export` is marked** in your custom Role;

[image: vApp -> Export]

Answer (score -1):

If you power off the VM and then the option will be available

Comment: OP reports server is powered down and accepted answer reports issue was permissions